# Listening global window events in stencilJS

Tags: javascript, dom-events, stenciljs

Let's say that I have something like this somewhere in application:

```
var event = new Event('build');
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

In stencilJS documentation, they say that you can listen to global events like this:

```
@Listen('body:scroll')
handleScroll(ev) {
    console.log('the body was scrolled', ev);
}
```

But I couldn't find way to listen to event that is emitted on window, like I can listen it with plain Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener('build', function (e) { 
  console.log('Event happened',e);
}, false);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I tried the stencil docs example and it did not work. I then changed the 'body' to 'window' and now I see the scroll event in the console.

```
@Listen('window:scroll')
handleScroll(ev) {
  console.log('the body was scrolled', ev);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import { Listen } from '@stencil/core';

@Listen('scroll', { target: 'window' })
handleScroll(ev) {
  console.log('the body was scrolled', ev);
}
```

Official documentation : https://stenciljs.com/docs/events

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i did a example of listening to a components published event in this [blog post](https://www.pwatoday.com/post/creating-a-side-menu-component-with-stencil-using-events-listen-and-slot).

But here is the general solution. I would use Stencils Event Emitter and emit from a component. Lets say you do this and emit an event from your component called fancyEvent...

```
@Event() fancyEvent: EventEmitter;
...
this.fancyEvent.emit($event);
```

To listen to this event on the window (i.e. in index.js), you can do one of two things. If you have a transpiler such as typescript, you can listen like this

```
@Listen('fancyEvent')
function doSomethingFancy() {}
```

But in vanilla es5 style javascript you can also listen to these custom events like this.

```
window.addEventListener('fancyEvent', function(e) {})
```